# Can I prevent Facebook on WP8 returning to the top of the newsfeed every time I hit "Back"?

Tags: facebook

The Facebook app "forgets" where I am in the newsfeed if I click a feed item (to comment or just read it) and then click the "back" button to return to the Newsfeed screen.

is this a "feature" of Windows Phone 8 or is this an issue with the app itself?

Comment: So glad this is fixed in the latest version.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a version of an application that is no longer available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with the app itself.

As it turns out, the official Facebook app for Windows Phone has actually been created by Microsoft.

[There are a lot of discussions about this app here and many people asking for many updates. Your best bet is to add your voice to these conversations](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions?query=facebook%20app).